# Programmatically remove an iOS app that has been attached to facebook

Tags: ios, facebook

http://1drv.ms/1DGx6Jl

I wonder if there is a way to remove an iOS app that has been connected (Logged in with Face) through the [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@"email"] allowLoginUI:YES ...] invocation ?  Essentially the mechanism of FBSession will install our app onto Facebook's "Logged in with Facebook".  The only way to remove it is for the user to manually do with the facebook app as shown in the image above.  We are looking for a way to do it from within our app, as not all users can be presumed knowledgeable in how to navigate to the right place as shown in the image.  Is there a way to do it inside iOS?  Or perhaps via Graph API?  We can assume that the user already logged in via Facebookapp and that we can obtain the facebook sesion key.  thank you in advance.

Comment: the image referred to in this paragraph is here: http://1drv.ms/1DGx6Jl